# Smart guides not working properly with custom guides in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, snapping, smart-guides

Here's a video showing my issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTNAyd7jpAs&ab_channel=niuage

I don't think I have any "snapping" enabled, apart from "smart guides", but it does seem to snap to something, and even moves my previous points... I also have "Align to pixel grid" turned off in the Transform window.

edit: even without smart guides, I seem to have an issue where closing a shape changes its shape slightly... In case that gives you a hit of the issue.

Comment: What version of illustrator? Be aware that turning pixel snapping off in older illustratir versions requires you to do so per object.

Comment: Good question, my illustrator is very old... 2015 CC.

Comment: @Robin - if you have a CC subscription, then just update it.  It costs no extra money.